# TSQL: format date with date & hour?

Tags: t-sql, datetime

In TSQL, I have a datetime variable that I want to display/group by:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH
```

`CONVERT()` seems to be able to pull out date formats, but only predefined ones and not something like MySQL's `DATE_FORMAT` which allows me to customize the format.

What function in TSQL lets me customize the date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (replace `Getdate()` function with your column name):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server 2012 or later?  If so you should be able to use the built-in [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function.